# How to blacken all pixels below certain brightness level in a grayscale image in Gimp?

Tags: color, gimp

I have a grayscale image in Gimp. I need to blacken all the least bright parts and only keep those that are above certain brightness threshold. For example, initially all grayscale pixels lie within 0-255 range of brightness. Those that are, say, below 128 need to become black and those that are above 128 need to stay intact.

How can I do it in Gimp?

Comment: Do you actually mean greyscale? Black & white only has two values, 0 & 255.

Comment: Sorry, I of course meant grayscale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Curves tool:

1. Set to "Freehand"
2. With the pen that appears, draw a line along the bottom edge (you can even stay a bit below) from the left corner up to the threshold value, to make a step in the diagonal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish such a task in a lot of ways in Gimp (even if I'd prefer to use [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij) or [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org) to play with pixel values), for example using the [Level tool](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-levels.html) or the [Select By Color](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html) tool.

A quick way is select all the pixels within the range you are interested and fill them with black.

Starting from the original image:

[image: Starting image]

You can use Select By Color tool (see also [this way](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4839/is-there-an-easy-way-to-select-by-histogram-range-in-gimp)) setting the preferred threshold (128 in your example), unchecking Antialiasing and Feather edge, and clicking on a black pixel:

[image: Select by color]

Using the [bucket fill](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-bucket-fill.html), fill the selection with a black value and obtain the desired image:

[image: Final image]

Note that the histogram now is flat for the gray values from 1 to 128, because they are set to 0.